# Add a route in osx's routing table programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, root

In my app i want to add a specific route in OSX's routing table which i can easily add through the terminal like this

```
 /sbin/route add -host X.X.X.X -interface en1
```

. for that i do some search on google and get to know that there is a file /etc/ppp/ip-up which consult by OS every time when a ppp link is up so i set my target to modify this file programmatically 
but then OS not allow me without root access so now i have to make possible this command to run programmatically now i found on google "i have to run a helper tool with my app because it can be run as root user" and get SMJobBless API and run it's sample. It was successful

but now i have a question how i can add this route in routing table by this helper tool i mean if i use CreateAuthorization and use this command to run with this! it again prompt for root password which user already give at the time of installation of this app, which is very very annoying
as in this sample app 
http://ideveloper.co/designing-writing-and-deploying-a-privileged-helper-on-mac-os-x/

now please tell me what i should do

Comment: isn't this working as expected? - sudo access only works for a single command / period of time. Think about the Keychain app . Each privileged access needs a journey through CreateAuth.

Comment: Are you signing the App with a DeveloperID or Mac App Store certificate?  In the case of security such as permissions like this, the ability to maintain a prior authorization requires the signature.  If you run the App with the same Bundle ID without the signature, the permissions will not be available to the App.  However, as long as you are using the standard authorization mechanisms, an app with the same BundleID and signed with the same Developer ID or Mac App Store ID will maintain its privileges across runs.

Comment: Reviewing the docs, a Mac App Store ID won't be appropriate here, as privilege escalation isn't allowed in sandboxed Apps per the Authorization Services docs, so in my above question, just consider Developer ID

Answer (score 0):

The best place to look is the source code for Apple's pppd and route tools.  Both should include code for adding routes.

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-307.0.1